# react use effects hooks : TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am learning react useEffects hooks, I am using JSON placeholder as my rest API,

I am able to display all posts, all users etc, now I want to display single post using useEffects

Here is my solution

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
function Data(){

const[post, setPost] = useState();

const[id, setId] = useState(1);

useEffect(()=>{
  console.log('call only once');
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
    .then(res =>{
      console.log(res);
      setPost(res.data);
    })
    .catch(error=>{
      console.log(error);
    })

}, []);

    return (
      <div>

      <h1> LIst of Posts </h1>
      <input type="text" value={id} onChange={e=>setId(e.target.value)} />

      <div>{post.title}</div>

      </div>
    );

}

export default Data;
```

Now when I run the app I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: useState({title:'value'});, read docs better

Comment: solved my problem, newbie problems OMG!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is trying to read an object property that doesn't exist yet. Try to use the call to construct a post object with a predetermined structure:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

function Data(){

  const[post, setPost] = useState({
    title: ''
  });

  const[id, setId] = useState(1);

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('call only once');
      axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
      .then(res =>{
        console.log(res);
        const { data } = res
        setPost({
          title: data.title
        });
      })
      .catch(error=>{
        console.log(error);
      })
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> LIst of Posts </h1>
      <input type="text" value={id} onChange={e=>setId(e.target.value)} />
      <div>{post.title}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Data;
```